# Как продолжить отсчёт во вложенном цикле?

Tags: java, циклы, for

```
public class TrucksAndContainers {
    public static final int MAX_CONTAINER_COUNT = 12;
    public static final int MAX_BOX_COUNT = 27;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int boxes = scanner.nextInt(); 

        int numberContainer ;
        int numberTrucks = 1;
        int containerCount = boxes / MAX_BOX_COUNT + (boxes % MAX_BOX_COUNT == 0 ? 0 : 1);
        int trucksCount = containerCount / MAX_CONTAINER_COUNT + (containerCount % MAX_CONTAINER_COUNT == 0 ? 0 :1);

        for(; numberTrucks <= trucksCount; numberTrucks++){
            System.out.println("Грузовик: " + numberTrucks);
            for(numberContainer = 1; numberContainer <= containerCount && numberContainer <= MAX_CONTAINER_COUNT; numberContainer++) {
                System.out.println("\t" + "Контейнер: " + numberContainer);
            }
        }
        System.out.print(System.lineSeparator());

        System.out.println("Необходимо:" + System.lineSeparator() + System.lineSeparator() + "грузовиков - " + trucksCount + " шт." + "\n" +
                "контейнеров - " + containerCount + " шт.");

    }

//Нужно что бы нумерация контейнеров продолжалась в новом грузовике:
//Грузовик: 1
//           Контейнер: 1
//           Контейнер: 2
//           Контейнер: 3
//           Контейнер: 4
//           Контейнер: 5
//           Контейнер: 6
//           Контейнер: 7
//           Контейнер: 8
//           Контейнер: 9
//           Контейнер: 10
//           Контейнер: 11
//           Контейнер: 12
//Грузовик: 2
//           Контейнер: 13
//           Контейнер: 14
//           Контейнер: 15
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class TrucksAndContainers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int container = 1;
        int truck = 1;
        int boxInCont = 27;
        int contInTruck = 12;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int box = scanner.nextInt();
        if (box == 0) {
            System.out.println("Необходимо:\nгрузовиков - " + "0 шт." + "\nконтейнеров - " + "0 шт.");
        }
        if (box > 0) {
            System.out.println("Грузовик: " + truck);
            System.out.println("\tКонтейнер: " + container);
            for (int i = 1; i <= box; i++) {
                System.out.println("\t\tЯщик: " + i);
                if (i == box) {
                    break;
                }
                if (i % (contInTruck * boxInCont) == 0) {
                    truck += 1;
                    System.out.println("Грузовик: " + truck);
                }
                if (i % boxInCont == 0) {
                    container += 1;
                    System.out.println("\tКонтейнер: " + container);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Необходимо:\nгрузовиков - " + truck + " шт." + "\nконтейнеров - " + container + " шт.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я так понимаю это задание с курсов типо скиллбокс, так вот у меня это решение прошло все тесты, если что.

Comment: Да, в самом начале пути изучения Java, два дня голову ломал, но видимо мозги еще не перестроились под мышление программиста, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: просто так не отправляй решение, постарайся посмотреть код и написать самостоятельно, а потом разобрать что непонятно. Задачи сделаны, чтоб ты разобрался, а не просто отправить решение. Но это мое сугубо личное мнение.

Comment: Я это понимаю, посидел и разобрался, просто списывать не моё =)